# How do I convert a Date in milliseconds into Date like in the database?

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I have an `@Entity` with field

```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false)
    private Date createdOn;
```

Which saves timestamp as

```
+----+------+------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| id | name | type       | units | description              | created_on          | retired_on          | core |
+----+------+------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|  1 | v1   | Double     | u1    | created via migration    | 2013-01-14 13:15:19 | NULL                |    1 |
|  2 | v2   | String     | u2    | created via migration    | 2013-01-14 13:15:19 | NULL                |    1 |
|  3 | v3   | BigDecimal | u3    | created via migration    | 2013-01-14 13:15:19 | NULL                |    0 |
| 27 | v4   | String     | u4    | created with web service | 2013-01-15 10:37:30 | 2013-01-15 11:27:48 |    1 |
+----+------+------------+-------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
```

When I retrieve the data I get Date object with value like

```
"createdOn": 1358198119000,
"createdOn": 1358198119000,
"createdOn": 1358198119000,
"createdOn": 1358275050000,
```

How can I convert them back into Date timestamped like `'2013-01-15 10:37:30'` and not like the number `1358198119000`?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. If you're getting back a `Date` object, that's already right, isn't it?

Comment: Are you really just trying to find out how to convert a `Date` into a string then? If so, the database side is irrelevant really. Have you looked at java.text.SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: @daydreamer Can you show us the `sql querie` that are getting data from DB. May be you can make some change there by using [DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: You should really give us a hint on how you are using the date object and its value. In the comments to an answer you say you need a date object (which you already got) and you speak about a specific format (YYYY-MM-DD ...) which is a plain presentation issue. It is unclear to me what your problem actually is. Are you asking for how to convert a timestamp in milliseconds into a date object?!

Answer (score 0):

This values are just miliseconds sinceepoch and they still represent proper `Date` objects. What means for your "timestamped"? As a `Timestamp` java class instance or just valid formated?

Something like this could help for first question with *yes* answer:

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(createdOn.getTime());
```

and something like this could help for second question with "yes" answer:

```
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String timestampedDate = formater.format(createdOn);
```

Comment: I guess I understand, but `format` is returning `String`, but for my API I need `Date`, I am not sure whats the best way to do this

Comment: But you already got `Date` object, haven't you? Date object data model is `long` value representing miliseconds pass since epoch time.

Comment: @daydreamer You can parse the date from string and create a date object. Like `Date date = formater.parse(timestampedDate )`

Comment: Or if you have your miliseconds as `long` just create new `Date` object by invoking `Date d = new Date(miliseconds_as_long_value)`. Is any suggestion - mine or anyone else fitting your problem or we just missing something?

Comment: @emka86 If he is getting the data from DB then he can also use DATE_FORMAT in sql.

Comment: @smit you know what I think? That @daydreamer has `toString` method for that entity class and inside he has such fragment like `"createdOn:" + createdOn.getTime();` and when he _print_ whole object he got time as miliseconds - is it possible?

Comment: @emka86 even if it is `toString`. It will convert to string as it was fetched. There is something miscellaneous going on and we cant say exactly untill we look at his code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your TemporalType to DATE

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false)
private Date createdOn;
```